# Amazon linux container4.0 can't not run in local machine. "failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops, aws-codebuild, containerd

Greeting :

Hello, I use Amazon linux2 images to run my CI/CD with Codebuild service.

And I do a lab to perpare build Amazon linxu with myself.

here it the Amazon images:
https://gallery.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard
public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:4.0

But . I Get problem when I docker pull images in my ec2

```
[root@ip-172-31-15-119 ~]# yum install docker -y 
[root@ip-172-31-15-119 ~]# systemctl restart docker 
[root@ip-172-31-15-119 ~]# systemctl status docker 
[root@ip-172-31-15-119 ~]# docker pull public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:4.0

[root@ip-172-31-15-119 ~]# docker images 
REPOSITORY                                              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard   4.0       d0c319128a8f   3 weeks ago   8.21GB

[root@ip-172-31-15-119 ~]# docker run -it public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:4.0 /bin/bash
....
...
...
**AND THE ERROR HAPPEN**
time="2023-06-05T07:41:01.288265549Z" level=info msg="stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown" module=libcontainerd
time="2023-06-05T07:41:01.288556319Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
Timed out trying to connect to internal docker host.
```

By the way...

```
[root@ip-172-31-15-119 ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                                              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux                  2023      dae5a17b8297   2 weeks ago   144MB
public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard   4.0       d0c319128a8f   3 weeks ago   8.21GB
```

Why 2023 is so small. , 4.0 is 8.21GB

I not sure the reason.
And I try this but no work.
https://blog.csdn.net/wangshuminjava/article/details/89310113?spm=1001.2101.3001.6650.2&utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2%7Edefault%7ECTRLIST%7ERate-2-89310113-blog-121489305.235%5Ev36%5Epc_relevant_anti_vip&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2%7Edefault%7ECTRLIST%7ERate-2-89310113-blog-121489305.235%5Ev36%5Epc_relevant_anti_vip&utm_relevant_index=1